# use kiiObject to save user data

Tags: javascript, cloud, kiicloud

In my app, every KiiUser has one hash table of data. But I have some problems using KiiObject to save data and get it next time.
I want to create an KiiObject with a specific URI when user registers so every time he logins I can import it with

```
KiiObject.objectWithURI(<URI>)
```

Alternatively, how to use objectWithJSON().
I don't want to use kiiQuery if I can avoid, as there is only one object for each user.

Can anyone give me an example of code how to create this Kiiobject when user registers and how to edit it every time he logins ; or every time he edits it and saves.
that's some of my current code but i don't get always the saved data back (the  saved hash table "data" undefined on the object)

```
    function performRegistration() {
    try {
        var user = KiiUser.userWithUsername(<username>, <password>);
        user.register({
            success: function(Auser) {
                var bucket = Auser.bucketWithName("data");
                data = bucket.createObject();
                data.set("data", {});
                data.saveAllFields({
                            success: function(theObject) {
                                console.log("Object saved!");
                                theObject.refresh({success:function(obj){
                                    data=obj;
                                     [....
                                     ...Some Code here to edit the...
                                     ...data object and save it....
                                      ...]
                                    Kii.logger("User registered: " + Auser);
                                }});
                            },
                            failure: function(theObject, errorString) {
                                console.log("Error saving object: " + errorString);
                            }
                        });

            },
            failure: function(theUser, anErrorString) {
                alert("Unable to register: " + anErrorString);
                Kii.logger("Unable to register user: " + anErrorString);
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        alert("Unable to register: " + e.message);
        Kii.logger("Unable to register user: " + e.message);
    }
}

// the user clicked the 'sign in' button
function performLogin() {
    KiiUser.authenticate(<username>, <password>, {
        success: function(Auser) {
            user = Auser;
            var bucket = user.bucketWithName("data"); // a KiiBucket
             var query = KiiQuery.queryWithClause();
             var queryCallbacks = {
             success: function(queryPerformed, r, nextQuery) {
                 console.log(r.constructor.name,r);
                 r[0].refresh({success:function(obj){
                     data=obj;
                     if(data.get("data")==undefined){
                         data.set("data",{});
                     }
                     data.save({success:function(Sobj){
                         data=Sobj;
                         [...
                         ...some data object manipilation then save it
                         ...]
                     }});

                 }});
             },
             failure: function(queryPerformed, anErrorString) {
             }
             };

             bucket.executeQuery(query, queryCallbacks);
        },
        // callback for failed registration
        failure: function(theUser, anErrorString) {
            alert("Unable to register: " + anErrorString);
            Kii.logger("Unable to register user: " + anErrorString);
        }
    });

};
Kii.initializeWithSite(<...>, <...>, KiiSite.US);
[...
other code
...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using KiiUser's custom fields?

It is described as "Manipulating the custom fields" in this page.

http://documentation.kii.com/en/guides/javascript/managing-users/user-attributes/

Check these links for detail of API:

- http://documentation.kii.com/references/js/storage/latest/symbols/KiiUser.html#set
- http://documentation.kii.com/references/js/storage/latest/symbols/KiiUser.html#get